# How can I stabilize this system using MPC?

Tags: control-theory, model-predictive-control

I'm a rookie in control science. I've been learning MPC recently and I got trouble with a plant:
$$
G(s)=\frac{-0.65 s+1}{-0.7 s^2-0.05 s+1.5}
$$
This is a nonstable plant with both positive poles and zeros. I tried some methods like PID and dyanamic matrix control (though it may not be very useful for nonstable plant). Unfortunately all of them failed. 
The only way that I succeed is by using the MPC Toolbox in matlab, but I cannot see the detail algorithm as the Toolbox only generate simulink model or matlab code (very simple)
I want to know is there a simple controller that can stabilize this plant and make no-error tracking for a step input? I really want an MPC implementation for it (will state space MPC be helpful?)
Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've found a solution by transfering the plant to a state-space model. I designed a state-feedback controller to stabilize the plant and applied a PID to track the reference input.
The structure of the controller is as shown in the following picture:
[image: System structure]

The feedback gain is created by the matlab function 'place'. Due to the positive zero, the plant is a nonminimum phase system. The PID parameters should be negative. I chose [P,I,D]=[-2, -1.5, 0]. The output is:
[image: response]

Comment: It can be noted that it is not needed to do both state feedback and PID. Namely, one can also augment the state space model of the system with an integral and then apply output feedback to that (i.e. combining state feedback and state estimator).

Comment: Also, you will need to see whether a state-feedback control law is a realistic one for the system. Do you have access to the "virtual" state? If not, an observer should be used.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Thanks. That's right. I read the book and found the step reference tracking can be achieved by replacing the PID in my picture with an integrator. And that kind of design makes the overall system to track reference even with disturbance and plant parameter variations.

Comment: @KBS Thanks. That's a good question. In this problem I focus on the controller design, so I'm just trying in the ideal condition with the accessible 'virtual' states. But I've also tried to build an observer. Because I have the exact transfer function, I can build an observer even without close loop feedback(i.e. open-loop observer). And thank you for your suggestions. Maybe we should always combine the state-feedback with observer. Because the'virtual' states are almost always unaccessible.